# kivy and python3 doesnt work on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, kivy

I have laptop with ubuntu 18.04 and i use for programming in python3. I decided to learn how i can make GUI and i chosen Kivy because of its multi-platform feature. After adding Kivy ppa and installing python3-kivy package with apt i tried to test the simple example with one button in the first page of kivy.org
but it return this errors:

screenshot from my terminal

[image]

after that i installed python-kivy package for python2 and run this test file again but this time there is no problem and the GUI showed correctly.

the program runs correctly

[image]

now i can use python2 but i always use python3 before and i want to use it with kivy. Can anyone tell me why this problem happens?

Comment: Install Kivy daily/nightly build, `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy-daily`

Comment: thank you kivy-daily works correctly.

Comment: Make sure to update dependancies to get it to work properly. Daily worked great otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for me was, with Python 3.6.5

Uninstall everything:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python3-kivy
sudo pip3 uninstall cython kivy
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then:

```
sudo pip3 install Cython==0.28.2
sudo pip3 install https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip
```

or in case you need version 1.9.1

```
sudo pip3 install Cython==0.23
sudo pip3 install kivy==1.9.1
```

Answer (score 1):

This bug, which I confirmed in Ubuntu 18.04, is probably the reason why python3-kivy was dropped from the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 19.04. This bug has been fixed and python3-kivy has been restored to the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 19.10 and later.

A later version of Kivy 1.11.1 (instead of 1.9.1 in Ubuntu 18.04) can be installed with `python3 -m pip install kivy` in a [Python virtual environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603935/pyvenv-vs-venv-vs-python-virtualenv-vs-virtualenv-and-python-3/603937#603937) using Python 3 virtual environment creator (*python3-virtualenv*) from the default Ubuntu repositories. Try running `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` before `python3 -m pip install kivy` to upgrade your pip3 to the latest version as I did.

Below are the results of running this [Hello World test program](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/kivy/kivy/5994/491939788) with Kivy 1.11.1 in a Python 3 virtual environment. The Python 3 code ran without any errors, detected OpenGL and my NVIDIA proprietary graphics driver, and output this window:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note that at this time the support for android python3 kivy is experimental.
Even though you may create the .apk chances are it will not work.

[image]